# Tier pricing across sizes

Tags: magento-1.9, tierprice, pricing

I have tier pricing on my custom shirts, but the tier pricing only works when you select the same size for all shirts, or in my case select a least 2 shirts in the same size.

My tier pricing is like this:

Price for 1 shirt is 200

Price pr shirt for 2-5 is 175

If the costumer chooses 3 medium the price is 525 (175 pr shirt)
If the costumer chooses 2 small and 2 medium the price is 700 (145 pr shirt)
But if the costumer chooses 1 small and 2 medium the price is 550 (175 for the mediums and 200 for the small)

Is there any way of combining sizes and still recieve the discount, so the costumer doesn't have to buy at least two of each size?